# How many priorities for arithmetic expressions?

Tags: combinatorics, trees

We have a sequence of integers $x_1, ..., x_n$.
How many different operations can we make by adding parentheses ?

**For instance**

With $1, 2$ we can make :

- $1 \oplus 2$

With $1, 2, 3$ we can make :

- $(1 \oplus 2) \oplus 3$
- $1 \oplus (2 \oplus 3)$

With $1, 2, 3, 4$ we can make :

- $((1\oplus 2)\oplus 3)\oplus 4$
- $(1\oplus 2)\oplus (3\oplus 4)$
- $1\oplus (2\oplus (3\oplus 4))$
- $1\oplus ((2\oplus 3)\oplus 4)$
- $(1\oplus (2\oplus 3))\oplus 4$

Where $\oplus$ is an arbitrary binary associative operator. I think it's related to how many structurally different binary trees we can make with $n$ leaves.

Comment: $(1\oplus 2)\oplus 3\oplus 4$ doesn't count?

Comment: It's the same as another already given expression depending on which priority (left or right) you use by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  There are $\frac 1{n+1}{2n \choose n}$ ways to make a properly matched string of $n$ pairs of parentheses.  You are looking for $C_{n-1}$ because each pair of parentheses is an operator and you have $n-1$ operators.  This is the second example on the Wikipedia page.  They are given in [OEIS A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108) and start $1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862, 16796, 58786, 208012, 742900, 2674440, 9694845, 35357670$